# Why can't I run my code? (Insertion Sort algorithm)?

Tags: python

```
def insertionSort(lst):
    k = 1
    while k < len(lst):
        x = lst.pop(k)
        insertInOrder(lst, k, x)
        k += 1

def insertInOrder(lst, k, x):
    while k >= 1 and lst[k-1] > x:
        k -= 1
        lst.insert(k, x)
```

This is the code I have done so far, but I am new to python and cant get it to run. Am I missing a `print` statement or a set?

Comment: What is the output that you wish to achieve?

Comment: these are only method you have to call them too

Comment: Please update your question with the code that calls `insertionSort`.

Comment: My outcome is to sort with an insertion Sort, so if u input 4,5,7,2,9 you can edit to 2,4,5,7,9

Comment: i guess I will use  a print

Comment: Is this your entire code?

Answer (score 0):

You have a slight error in your 1st `while` test in `insertInOrder`. Here's a repaired version. I've added a `print` call so you can see how the sort progresses.

```
def insertionSort(lst):
    k = 1
    while k < len(lst):
        x = lst.pop(k)
        insertInOrder(lst, k, x)
        k += 1

def insertInOrder(lst, k, x):
    print(k, x, lst)
    while k > 0 and lst[k-1] > x:
        k -= 1
    lst.insert(k, x)

a = [4, 5, 7, 2, 9]
print(a)
insertionSort(a)
print(a)
```

**output**

```
[4, 5, 7, 2, 9]
1 5 [4, 7, 2, 9]
2 7 [4, 5, 2, 9]
3 2 [4, 5, 7, 9]
4 9 [2, 4, 5, 7]
[2, 4, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: Is there a way to code this without using any loop statements, as I would like to break it down even more

Comment: @FindingJango I don't think so. Selection sort is an O(n²) sort, since it has to do a loop to select each item, and then another loop to find the insertion position for each item. Actually, this implementation has 2 extra "hidden" loops, since `.pop` has to move all items after the popped one down to fill the gap, and `.insert` has to move all items after the insertion position up to make room, but both of those loops run at C speed.

Comment: @FindingJango I wouldn't worry too much about efficiency here. The point of the exercise is to become familiar with the insertion sort algorithm. It's not actually practical to use it for sorting real data, since Python's TimSort uses a much more efficient algorithm, and it runs at C speed.

Comment: Ah gotcha, yh so far I do get the insertion sort. I just had a small mistake there and wasnt sure how to print it properly.